# Please explain me that vk css icons trick

Tags: css, gif, css-sprites, vk

I've seen some interesting css trick on vk.vom recently

```
background: url(/images/icons/mono_iconset.gif?8) no-repeat left -237px;
width: 15px;
height: 11px;
```

Here is this spritesheet: [Spritesheet](https://vk.com/images/icons/mono_iconset.gif?8).

How is this works?

Comment: What exactly do you wanna know? Why and how to use spritemaps?

Comment: What trick? It's just using the background image as a sprite sheet and moving its' positioning to fit the 15px x 11px area.

Comment: I want to know what is it and how it works. I mean this question mark and number (of frame?) after it. I noticed that all icons have different heights.

Comment: `?` has nothing to do here, its the `left -237px` which determines which icon to show

Comment: Oh.. I was hoping that it is some secret useful css trick.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?` has nothing to do here, its the `left -237px` which determines which icon to show.

It is the `background-position: x y` along with height that determines which part of an image needs to be shown.

More about css sprites http://cssglobe.com/creating-easy-and-useful-css-sprites/

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the URL parameters have nothing to do with the spritemap itself.

Different heights, on the other hand, are handled by the `height` in the CSS you provided. Moreover, the y-offset determines which icon will be used.

Answer (score 0):

The URL parameter is probably inserted to avoid problems with caching when deploying a new version of that stylesheet. If you append something using the `query string` (like ?8), the browser will be tricked into thinking this is a whole other file, so it will discard the cached file and download the new one instead.

The "trick" you are looking for is a CSS sprite. Basicly, every icon is loaded into a single image and the icons in the sprite are used as a background image for a fixed-width container (like an `anchor` with `display: block;` or a `div`). Then, when playing around with the `backgound-position` property, different parts of the sprite will be visible.

Read more about CSS sprites in [this article](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).